# Syncing a table records with a Service response frequently

Tags: mysql, oracle, wcf, asp.net-web-api

I am requesting data from a service whose response in stored in a database.First, I have an empty table, whenever I make my very first request the records from the service comes to my database table.

from now, whenever I make second request, the service will provide me some records which may be same as my first response, may be new records, may be updated records etc.

my query is to how to update my table with respect to the responses coming from the service during my second request on-wards? so that Unchanged records will remain same, New records will be added, updated records will be updated.Do I need to write any stored procedure on my DB or any workaround ?what might be the scenario if I use Nomysql DB's like mongo DB ?
Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Locate whichever subset of the service response identifies a record; this should be set as the primary key in your database table, or else a secondary key over which a uniqueness constraint is enforced.
2. In MySQL, use [`INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/insert-on-duplicate.html).

Comment: Response from service is a collection of records

Comment: @KarthikDheeraj: Presumably each record consists of fields, some subset of which can be used to uniquely identify it?  If not, how can you ever hope to tell whether you're looking at a pre-existing record that has been updated or an entirely new record?

Comment: It should also delete the records from table which not present in response.

Comment: @KarthikDheeraj: Then you may as well delete all records from the table and repopulate it afresh from the new service response.